# goal status in Callback in actionserver in C++

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
My client sends the goal but gets status ABORTED instead of SUCCEEDED and server gives following error:

```
[ WARN] [1337607518.317686823]: Your executeCallback did not set the goal to a terminal status. This is a bug in your ActionServer implementation. Fix your code! For now, the ActionServer will set this goal to aborted
```

My callback is

```
void startnode(const my_msgs::myGoalConstPtr& goal, Server* as)
{ 
  my_msgs::myResult result_;
  result_.result = 1;
  as->setSucceeded(result_);
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem??
Thanks in advance.
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34458/goal-status-in-callback-in-actionserver-in-c++/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GioRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4280/gioros/) on 2014-07-31**:
Hi, I know this is an old post. But i have your same problem. Did you solve it??
I have been trying to solve by myself for a week with no dice!!!
Could you help me???
Thanks

**Comment by [Yael Green](https://answers.ros.org/users/25899/yael-green/) on 2016-03-16**:
Hi, I am having the same issue, do you have a lead?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-12-01**:
This unanswered thread was closed due to 'off-topic or outdated', but I find the same error can still happen today and no other threads discuss this error. So I reopened it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As pointed out by the error message, fix the termination state in your Action Server. In [rospy sample](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Server%20using%20the%20Execute%20Callback%20%28Python%29), not calling [set_succeeded](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Server%20using%20the%20Execute%20Callback%20%28Python%29#CA-3786eb3a74acabd7ea4ba08b8b23ad9583d5bd79_490) can lead to the error in this question. OP asks for C++ but I haven't tried, so I can only assume that the equivalent is [setSucceeded](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29#CA-4489f75655c29f8fd70e22d2b43906c08f386f4e_67).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1